# How to Show Flash Message after adding / Deleting Data using Ajax in Laravel; 8

Tags: laravel

Need help for Showing Flash Message after adding / Deleting Data using Ajax in Laravel 8
i included the file "flash-message.blade.php"

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
  @include('flash-message')
```

My Controller File

```
 public function deleteData(Request $req) 
    {
        $deletedata = buffalodata::destroy($req->id); 
         return response()->json( $deletedata );
    }
```

Ajax Call for Delete Data

```
    $(document).on('click', '#footer_delete_button', function() { 

            $.ajax({

                type:'post',
                url: '/deleteData',
                data:{
                    '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                    'id'    : $('.did').text()
                    },

                        success: function(data) {
                            console.log("Success");
                            $('.item' + $('.did').text()).remove();
                                
                                location.reload()
                        }
                });


            });
```

Thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 1):

You can use ***https://github.com/stanlemon/jGrowl*** after deleting successfully

I have used this as shown below:

Add this script in your **layout.blade.php** file

```
function popUpMessage(colorTheme, message) {
        $.jGrowl(message,
            {
                theme: colorTheme
            }
        );
    }
```

For success call this:

```
popUpMessage('bg-success', "Deleted successfully");
```

For error call this:

```
popUpMessage('bg-danger', "Some error occured");
```

'***bg-success***' and '***bg-danger***' are ***bootstrap classes***, you can use your own

If you want to flash session messages from controller then you can use:

Add this to your **flash-message.blade.php**

```
@if (session()->has('success'))
    <script>
        popUpMessage('bg-success', "{{ session()->get('success') }}" );
    </script>
@elseif (session()->has('error'))
    <script>
        popUpMessage('bg-danger', "{{ session()->get('error') }}");
    </script>
@endif
```

Then after successfully deleting you can call this form controller:

```
    session()->flash('success', 'Deleted Successfully');
```

For error

```
    session()->flash('error', 'Some error occurred');
```

As you are using ajax then don't use ***location.reload()***